# How to form a join query in mysql to filter records based on some status condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Consider I have table t1

| id | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row1 |
| 2 | row2 |
| 3 | row3 |
| 4 | row4 |

and another table t2

| id | t1_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | PG |
| 2 | 2 | S |
| 3 | 1 | CG |
| 4 | 1 | S |
| 5 | 3 | CG |

t1 has one2many relationship with t2.

The t1_id has multiple entries in t2 table because t2's status sequence goes on like
**PG > CG >S**.

So it can have separate entry for each status it passes through.

Once it reaches status S we should not select that t1_id even if it has any of the previous statuses like PG or CG

I want to do left join like **t1 left join t2** based on t1 id
And another condition like t2's status should not have **S**.

So the expected result should be

| t1_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | CG |
| 4 | null |

How can I achieve this ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First retrieve t1_id where status 'S' exists and ignore those t1_id from query if any other status info for that t1_id is existed in the table.

```
-- MySQL (v5.7)

SELECT t.id t1_id, p.status
FROM t1 t
LEFT JOIN t2 p
       ON t.id = p.t1_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM t2
                  WHERE t1_id = t.id AND status = 'S');
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2a38e8a8696b68c15f8e95a28f244c86

Comment: Hi @Vanjith please check this query and let me know if any query regard this.

Comment: Hi @Rahul sorry I forgot to mention, I need to avoid sub queries, thats the main concern here. And I found the solution using group by  and having